# Mongoose: Change validations w.r.t value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation

I have a sample schema:

```
{
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    status: {type: String, enum: ['draft', 'status1', 'status2']},
    value1: {type: String, required: true},
    value2: {type: String, required: true}
}
```

Other than `required: true`, I also have some other validations on `value1` and `value2`, like `RegExp`

```
schema.path('title', function (value) { ... });
schema.path('value1', function (value) { ... });
schema.path('value2', function (value) { ... });
```

I want to run different validation if the `status == draft`.
For e.g. Only `title` is `required` and other validations are ignored.

Currently i'm doing it this way:

```
schema.method('saveDraft', function(next) {
    if (this.status == 'draft') {
        schema.set('validateBeforeSave', false);

        if (!this.title || this.title.length == 0)
            return next(Error("`title` is required"));
    }

    this.save(next);
});
```

But this force me to use `mydocument.saveDraft(cb)`.

Is it possible to do using `mydocument.save(cb)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to run different validations depending on current value.

I applied a pre validator hook:

```
schema.pre('validate', function preValidate(next) {
    if (this.status == 'draft') {
        // Make all fields optional
        _.each(_.keys(schema.paths), function (attr) {
            schema.path(attr).required(false);
        });

        var draftRequiredMap = ['title']; // Based on condition, our required fields are here.
        _.each(draftRequiredMap, function (attr) {
            schema.path(attr).required(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Overwrite the save method for your schema, it will validate then call the standard save method (that you would have saved somewhere in your code)
- Use the [pre save hook](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) (assuming you are using mongoose)

  ```
  schema.pre('save', function(next){
      ...
      next();
  });
  ```

Comment: I tried overriding the the save method, but it is not calling.

`schema.method('save', func() { ... });`

Comment: By using pre save hook, it runs the default validate function first. If that fails, it never goes to pre save.

Comment: You probably want to remove the `require` validators as it will always get triggered before `pre` hooks. And apply your validation manually in the `pre` hook.